# Heavy calculations and displaying data without blocking UI

Tags: javascript, user-interface, d3.js, nonblocking, web-worker

I am working on an application which will do statistical calculations and display the resulting data afterwards with D3.js.

For the most part I am able to avoid blocking the UI, by passing the actual calculations to a [WebWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

After the calculations are done the data points will be **sorted** and displayed with d3.js. It is nasty ([though possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133918/parsing-xml-in-web-workers)) to work with DOM elements in a WebWorker, even though the worker itself can not interact with the DOM. Still I really would like to avoid that.

Let's say I have about 1 million data points, which will be sorted and displayed with d3. **How do I avoid that the UI freezes, when js performs this task?**

**An idea**, which works to some extend:

d3 code looks something like this:

```
d3.select ...
.sort ...
.enter ...
.attr ...
.attr ...
.style ...
```

This would all be executed in once. To give the [render queue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) the opportunity to render in between things you could do something like this:

```
 let prom = new Promise((re, rj) => {
            setTimeout(function() {
                let val = d3.select ...
                            .sort ...
                            .enter ...
                re(val);            
              }, 0);
        });

prom.then(val => {
    val = val.attr ...
            .attr ...
            .style ...
});
```

The first part of the d3 operations on the data will be pushed on the callback queue, the render queue has an opportunity to render and then the next part of the d3 code will be executed (more complex model with more than one promise possible). Still this **does not solve the problem**. It may be a little bit better than executing everything at once, but the UI will still freeze, if the single parts itself take too long.

Does anyone know a good solutions to this problem?

Comment: Can you batch the results into say 50 batches of 20,000?

Comment: @Archer Already thought about that. This is usually a good idea, but the situation does not allow that. I some situations I want to sort all (1 Mio) datapoints and display them in one chart.

Comment: Can you not sort them in the WebWorker before returning them (in batches), thereby solving that particular problem?

Comment: Also a good idea, which unfortunately don't want to do. Why? The user can receive the data in a sorted or unsorted way, depending how he needs it. At a later point we might also sort for different criteria.

Comment: Right okay - sounds like an interesting problem, and I look forward to seeing how you resolve it :)

Comment: Furthermore I think the sorting only adds to the problem, but is not the main problem. D3 will take time to "make" large charts, no matter if sorted or unsorted

Comment: @Archer yea, I am also looking forward to see me solve it xD

Comment: @User12547645 forget about programming, computers and D3. Let's talk about dataviz. Why would you want to show 1 million data points to the user?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado good point. The data will be displayed in a bar chart. And the user can hover with his / her mouse over the cart and every bar will display a tooltip on hover which displays the data property. This is why displaying all the data instead of just an aggregation is necessary

Comment: But how many bars do you plan to display? Even if each bar is just 1px wide, you won't have more than 1000 bars...

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Even with lower numbers the UI starts to block. I really get you point, still this is not the problem here. The drawing (and sorting) of the chart will block the UI, even with a lot less elements

Comment: In that case you have another problem, because a bar chart won't break anything. At this point, we can only help you if you provide a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using SVG which must add Dom elements to represent all your bars. Even though you are using web workers to do your heavy processing, adding those thousands of Dom elements, calculating the image, and painting is what is locking the main thread.

You could help resolve this by using canvas instead which doesn't have the issue of tons of Dom elements and works with the GPU more. D3 V4 supports canvas, but would require some re-architecting to get it to work. You can also make it progressively render. The tricky bit would be adding your interactions since you don't have the individual elements to attach listeners too.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint. I will try that

Answer (score 0):

As elliot pointed out already, the problem is that D3 will add so many elements to the DOM. To avoid blocking the main thread it would be possible to draw the data in chunks, like suggested [here](https://engineering.mongodb.com/post/digging-into-d3-internals-to-eliminate-jank-over-large-data-sets)

I would still need to sort first, though.